# How to call ASP.NET Core Web APIs from ASP.NET Webform using HttpClient?

Tags: webforms, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have 2 different project. I created web apis project in ASP.NET CORE 3.1 (MVC). Another I created ASP.NET webforms website (.NET Framework 4.8). I am unbale to call .NET Core web apis from webforms website. But I am able to call .NET core apis from another .net core project using HttpClient using same code which I added in Page_Load() method.

ASP.NET Core 3.1 [API Controller Code]

```
namespace User
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {   
        [HttpGet("GetUserDetailsByUserName/{userName}")]
        public IActionResult GetUserDetailsByUserName(string userName)
        {
            //fetch data from database based on userName
        }
        
        [HttpPost("AddNewUser")]        
        public ActionResult AddNewUser([FromBody] UserModel userModel)
        {
            //save new user data in database
        }       
    }
}
```

ASP.NET Webform (.Net Framework 4.8)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public partial class User : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //calling GetUserDetailsByUserName();
            
            HttpClient httpClient = Client.GetClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://*******/");   //DOT_NET_CORE_WEBSITE_URL
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "TOKEN");  
            
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage;
            httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://*******/GetUserDetailsByUserName/{userName}");    //HERE NOT GETTING ANY RESPONSE 
            httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string result = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }       
    }
    
    public class Client
    {
        public static HttpClient GetClient()
        {
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
            httpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            return httpClient;
        }
    }
    
    public class UserModel
    {
        public string UserName{get;set;}
        public string Password{get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set `Page.Async` to `true`? Does your web.config set `httpRuntime.targetFramework` to 4.5 or greater? [More info in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058).

Comment: I haven't set `Page.Async` to `true`. I set `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" requestValidationMode="4.0" executionTimeout="110" targetFramework="4.8" />` in web.config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have 2 different project. I created web apis project in ASP.NET CORE
> 3.1 (MVC). Another I created ASP.NET webforms website (.NET Framework 4.8). I am unbale to call .NET Core web apis from webforms website. But I am able to call .NET core apis from another .net core project
> using HttpClient using same code which I added in Page_Load() method.

The breaking point for your request failure is incorrect [httpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-8.0) construction. If you could debug and watch your request you would see your extended URI is not included with your `httpClient.BaseAddress` consequently, request doesn't hit the endpoint. As you can see below:

[image]

**Note:** Please also double check that you have [`Async="true"` enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45#CreatingAsynchGizmos). You can [check here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45#CreatingAsynchGizmos)

> How to call ASP.NET Core Web APIs from ASP.NET Webform using
> HttpClient?

Actually, over the time singnificant improvement has implemented on [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-8.0) request. However, you are using [ASP.NET Web Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45#CreatingAsynchGizmos), hence, you should consider the appropiate way which [ASP.NET Web Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45#CreatingAsynchGizmos) supports.

To make a successful Http request  from ASP.NET Web Forms to [Asp.net Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#routing-and-url-paths) you could try either way below:

Http Request Way 1:

```cs
            HttpClient httpClient = Client.GetClient();
            //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "TOKEN");
            var userName = "Kiron";
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage;
            httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync($"https://localhost:7132/api/User/GetUserDetailsByUserName/{userName}");    //HERE NOT GETTING ANY RESPONSE
            httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string result = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Http Request Way 2:

```cs
            HttpClient httpClient2 = Client.GetClient();
            var userName = "Kiron";
            var response = await httpClient2.GetAsync($"https://localhost:7132/api/User/GetUserDetailsByUserName/{userName}");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

Debugging Findings:

[image]

Complete Way In ASP.NET Web Forms:

```cs
       protected  void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(CallAspnetCoreWebAPI));
        }

        static readonly HttpClient client = Client.GetClient();
        private  async Task CallAspnetCoreWebAPI()
        {
            var userName = "Kiron";
            var response = await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:7132/api/User/GetUserDetailsByUserName/{userName}");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var readResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }


        }
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [ASP.NET Web Forms Http Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45).

Comment: Thank you so much @Md Farid Uddin Kiron. now able to call web apis from webform.

Comment: How to pass and get data from this `CallAspnetCoreWebAPI` method? or is there any other way to call the `CallAspnetCoreWebAPI` API without using `RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask()`? ex: `var result = CallAspnetCoreWebAPI();`

Comment: Actually its, asp.net web form so lastest most syntax might not implemented here. I have shown you the Microsoft recomended approach but still if you have any concern, you could post a new question reagarding your new concern, I could check that to assist you there. Thanks for your response.

Comment: okay, I will create a new question regarding my new concern.